# Magnolia 6.0 Tomcat 9 Forbidden Access /.resources*

Tags: java, tomcat, magnolia

Currently I have a small problem, I have updated magnolia from 5.5.4 to 6.0 as far everything goes well.

Now I have looked at my website and had to find that all css and js files are not loaded and returned from the tomcat accordingly all with 403 Forbidden.

I have already checked the GzipFilterChain and Authorized returns true but the request runs into 403 too.

In Magnolia Security i granted the permission to user anonymus that /.resources is "Get and Post" too but nothing seems to work.

are there any other soloutions to get it work?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There’s no change in security between those two versions so everything should work as usual. However Tomcat 9 is more strict than Tomcat 8 was about some characters being part of url. It’s mentioned in upgrade notes of Magnolia in connection with delivery endpoints https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Upgrading+to+Magnolia+6.0.x#UpgradingtoMagnolia6.0.x-Serverconfigurationwithrelaxedquerychars
Perhaps that is source of your issue.
If this doesn’t help, to rule out security you can also temporarily set `enabled=false` to `URISecurityFilter` in filter chain.